# Floating Div that will not effect the page behind

Tags: html, authentication, space

i am attempting to make a div that will become a login area, so when you click on login on the navbar the div appears and you type in the details, and it goes away i haven't got code yet as i don't know where to start please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that's what you are looking for
http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: thanks not sure how to do it all but i'm sure i will pull through